# find y for $y\sqrt{y^2+x^2}dx-x(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y\sqrt{y^2+x^2}dx-x(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})dy=0$$

$$y\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-x(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

$$\frac{y}{x}\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

$z=\frac{y}{x}\Rightarrow zx=y\Rightarrow z^2x^2=y^2$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dz}{dx}+z$

$$z\sqrt{z^2x^2+x^2}-(x+\sqrt{z^2x^2+x^2})(x\frac{dz}{dx}+z)=0$$

$$zx\sqrt{z^2+1}-(x^2+x\sqrt{z^2+1})(x\frac{dz}{dx}+z)=0$$

$$zx\sqrt{z^2+1}-(x^3\frac{dz}{dx}+x^2z+x^2\sqrt{z^2+1}\frac{dz}{dx}+zx\sqrt{z^2+1})=0$$

$$-x^3\frac{dz}{dx}-x^2z-x^2\sqrt{z^2+1}\frac{dz}{dx}=0$$

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplify a little more
$$\frac{y}{x}\sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2+1} - \left(1+\sqrt{\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^2+1} \right) \frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Let $z=\frac{y(x)}{x}$ then $dz = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{y(x)}{x} \right) dx= \frac{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}{x^2} dx$

This implies $$
\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{dy}{dx} &=& \frac{1}{x} \left( \frac{dz}{dx}x^2+y \right) \\ 
&=&\frac{1}{x} \left( \frac{dz}{dx}x^2+zx \right) \\ 
&=&x\frac{dz}{dx}+z \\ 
\end{array}$$

Put it back in and simplify

$$z\sqrt{z^2+1} - (1+\sqrt{z^2+1})\left(x\frac{dz}{dx}+z\right)=0$$

$$x \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{z\sqrt{z^2+1}}{1+\sqrt{z^2+1}}-z=-\frac{z}{1+\sqrt{z^2+1}}$$

Some algebraic manipulations yield
$$ -\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{1+\sqrt{z^2+1}}{z} dz $$

Integrating both sides...

Comment: how did you got the 1(not in the sqrt) in $(1+\sqrt{ (\frac{y}{x} )^2+1}) \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: ah! by dividing both sides by $x$?

Comment: $\frac{y}{x}\sqrt{y^2+x^2}-(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ ?

Comment: yes, from that equation. move $x$ inside the square root makes it become $x^2$...

Comment: but it is not multiplication $(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2})$ how can I move $x$ inside?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}(x+\sqrt{y^2+x^2}) = \frac{1}{x}x+\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{y^2+x^2} =  \frac{1}{x}x+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}(y^2+x^2)} $

Comment: see my updated answer... it should be good to go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38662/discussion-between-gbox-and-kensaii).